# How to prevent dragging of an <image> element inside a <svg>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am building an editor that uses an SVG element as the canvas. It provides custom drag-and-drop behavior to drag elements inside the svg around. However, when I try to drag an `<image>` tag, the native browser drag behavior where you're dragging a "ghost" of the image kicks in. How do I stop it?

I tried setting `user-select: none` in CSS, which does prevent selecting text but not dragging the image. I tried setting the HTML `draggable="false"` property, which has no effect in SVG. I even tried to cancel the `ondragstart` event, which doesn't seem to fire at all.

```html
<svg>
  <image draggable="false" style="user-select: none;" ondragstart="return false" href="https://wehles.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/opamp.png?w=147"></image>
</svg>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1dnfpray/

How do I prevent the image from being dragged, so that I can implement my own drag behavior?

Comment: _"I tried setting user-select: none in CSS"_ may you add that attempt to the question?

Comment: which browser and OS? I'm running chrome on ubuntu 20.04 and can't reproduce.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Firefox (Windows 10).  Chrome does not drag the image even without any attribute, style or event handler.

Comment: I can also drag the image in Firefox (macOS)

Comment: Yea this is in firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cancel the `mousedown` event, the drag is prevented:

```html
<svg>
  <image draggable="false" style="user-select: none;" onmousedown="return false" href="https://wehles.files.wordpress.com/2020/05/opamp.png?w=147"></image>
</svg>
```

You'll need to handle that event anyway, if you want to implement your own dragging behaviour.

Comment: Does that correspond with `stopPropegation` or `preventDefault`? I'm using React which normally attaches a passive listener rather than actually setting `onmousedown` on. If there is a solution that works with idiomatic React handlers, that would be preferred, but if returning false is the only way, I'll have to do some ugly hack.

Comment: It's `preventDefault`, and indeed you need a non-passive listener for it to work. But I'm sure React doesn't always use passive listeners; that would be silly. You can just [call `preventDefault`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) on the event object.